# Excel - Conditional format cells based on a column and duplicate and another column's value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How would i conditional format a column for duplicate values if the cell is a duplicate of another value of same column AND another column contains the same value as the duplicate, without adding a conditional column?

Example, ID # in index 1 and 2, and 6 and 7, will get highlighted because they have the same ID and they have the same invoice type, but 3 and 4 does not need get highlighted

Only if invoice type = Billed or Sold and ID # match in different rows, then we would conditional format the ID column

| Index | Invoice Type | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Biled | **1234** |
| 2 | Billed | **1234** |
| 3 | Correction | 1234 |
| 4 | Correction | 1234 |
| 5 | Billed | 1235 |
| 6 | Sold | **1235** |
| 7 | Sold | **1235** |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that “Invoice Type” and “ID” are Columns `B` and `C`,
and that you have data in Rows 2 through 99,
you should “use a formula to determine which cells to format”,
with this formula:

```
=AND(OR(TRIM(B2)="Billed",TRIM(B2)="Sold"), SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(B$2:B$99)=TRIM(B2)), --(TRIM(C$2:C$99)=TRIM(C2)))>=2)
```

Data in the question (with typo):

[image: index 6 and 7 are highlighted]

With typo fixed:

[image: index 1, 2, 6 and 7 are highlighted]

Comment: the formula applies to the the previous IDs; when i enter an ID in cell 1 for example and enter the same ID in cell 2 below it, it doesnt format cell 2 but rather cell 1

Answer (score -1):

Select Range ID and go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**- select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enter the formula and set Format:

```
=IF(OR(B2="Biled",B2="Sold"),SUMPRODUCT((B2=$B$2:$B$8)*(C2=$C$2:$C$8)),0)>1
```

[image]

Comment: how would i modify the formula to apply to the whole column instead of just a range of cells?

Comment: the formula applies to the the previous IDs; when i enter an ID in cell 1 for example and enter the same ID in cell 2 below it, it doesnt format cell 2 but rather cell 1